# Is there any way to fill math equation using text controls? Or add equation to existing word document programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ms-word, equation

I have word template with fillable text controls and equations. Is there any way to use these text controls in existing math equations? When I'm trying to perform this idea, I face the error:

> Word error while trying to open file. Try following these steps....

If this method cannot be used, maybe someone knows how to create (or fill) math equation in word document programmatically using c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that you are developing an ASP.NET application where you can't automate MS Office applications, for such cases MS states the following:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.